# Portable satellite antena

Tags: internet, satellite

Here is the thing, I travel a lot and every so often I get to a hotel or a remote location where internet is either slow (London), country has a censorship (UAE) or there is no Internet at all. The only solution is to get a satellite network.

I am wondering how viable is that?

So far the smallest satellite antena I've found is http://www.winegard.com/carryout/, which doesn't look promising in terms of size and weight. Are there any smaller gadgets that could help me po get fast satellite connection pretty much anywhere around the world?

---

Just found http://www.groundcontrol.com/Hughes_9202_BGAN.htm. Looks good, but the speed isn't amazing. Looking to hear if anyone knows alternatives.